# How to chain suscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

Hi I am trying to chain following subscriptions.

```
  changeBranch() {
const bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef = this.bottomSheet.open(CCSBranchComponent, {
  data: this.branches
});
this.subscription.add(bottomSheetRef.instance.change.subscribe((branch: Branch) => {
  this.branchInfo = `Description : ${branch.author}\nAuthor : ${branch.id}\nCreated date :${branch.created}`;
  this.blockpointBranchForm.get('branch').setValue(branch.id);
}));
this.subscription.add(bottomSheetRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
this.returnSelectedBranch.emit(this.blockpointBranchForm.get('branch').value);
}));
```

}

Here if bottomSheetRef.instance.change.subscribe is called before the sheet loads, it throws undefined. So i am trying the implement something that looks like this

```
this.subscription.add(this.bottomSheet.open(CCSBranchComponent, {
  data: this.branches
}).instance.change.subscribe((branch: Branch) => {
  this.branchInfo = `Description : ${branch.author}\nAuthor : ${branch.id}\nCreated date :${branch.created}`;
  this.blockpointBranchForm.get('branch').setValue(branch.id);
}).afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
this.returnSelectedBranch.emit(this.blockpointBranchForm.get('branch').value);
}));
```

Here the second subscribe is called on the subscription returns by first. How do I access the observable in the chain?

Comment: Subscription.add does't chain events, it just adds a subscription for releasing it later e.g. onNgDestroy to avoid memory leaks. If you want to create stream of events you have to use rxjs operator e.g. mergeMap, switchMap, depending on your use case.

Comment: You don't chain subscriptions, a subscription is the final consumer. You chain streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is to chain the the actions what are done when subscribing.

You can achieve this by

```js
bottemsheetRef.instance.change.pipe(
 switchmap(resultFromChange => bottomSheetRef.afterDismissed
).subsbribe(resultFromAfterDismissed => {// do whatever you like})
```